# Function argument with maps in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm getting my feet wet with Clojure the past couple of day and came across this piece of code:

```
(defn reduce-example
  [new-map [key val]]
  (assoc new-map key (inc val)))

(reduce reduce-example
        {}
        {:max 30 :min 10})
; => {:max 31, :min 11}
```

I am confused about the function argument in `reduce-example`, more specifically this: `new-map [key value]`

From what I studied so far and after the function name, you can declare the number of arguments (arities). For example `[x y z]`, but what does `[new-map [key value]]` mean? of course it can extract the key and value but how? how should I interpret this function argument?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_sequential_destructuring ; the [key value] takes a parameter which is a sequence and assigns the first value to key and the second to value. Also note that when passing a map to a function like reduce, it is automatically converted into a sequence of vectors. Try (seq {:max 30 :min 30}) and you'll see what I mean. This also shows you where the [key value] that is being passed into reduce-example is coming from.

Answer (score 6):

`[new-map [key value]]` mean the function expect two argument:

- first one will bind to name `new-map`
- second one (should be a sequential type with 2 elements inside) . The
  elements inside will bind to `key` and `value`

Clojure has an ability of [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring)

Comment: Slightly more accurate: *second one should be a sequential type, Its first element will bind to `key`, its second to `value`*.